# How can I rectify Replacement filler cap?

Tags: oil, valve-cover

Civic coupe vti 1999.

I have just received my replacement filler cap off eBay and it does fit!

However I noticed some white stuff around a bit the outer part of the rubber seal and thought it was dirt.  Trying to remove it with some tissue the whole seal came off then I realised it’s actually underlying glue which wasn’t covered by the seal.  The seal coming off so easily shows it was a poor manufacturing job I guess.

Anyway im tired of this filler cap issue.  Right now to remove the seal u really need to poke with your nails so I could just at least temporarily use car by manually put seal into place and every time I remove the cap just ensure the rubber is still in place as it’s not moving easily even without glue.

I could also dab a little bit of super glue(?) Where existing glue is.

What do you recommenced?If the existing or super glue sticks out a little either side of the rubber will that matter as the original glue did will that matter in which case I’ll need to clean and glue until I get it right?

I imagine I could send it back but would rather avoid it.  They may also argue I shouldn’t have picked at the visible glue but of course I would how do I know of it is dirt that just needed picking out or glue.  Plus the glue job was obviously poor to begin with.

Thanks[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually "super glue" type adhesives don't stick well to materials like that gasket is made of.  It should stay put in the groove for it without any glue.  If not, then it's not the right size or you stretched it out messing with it.

Go to a local hardware or auto parts store and see if you can find a suitable o-ring that will fit properly.

If you have to, just put the o-ring on and tighten the cap as intended.  Over time the o-ring will tend to stick to either the cap or the valve cover.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to solve your dilemma is with rubber cement. This would just be replacement glue to keep the o-ring in place. Put some around the entire circumference on the cap and o-ring separately. Wait until the glue becomes tacky on both parts, then place the o-ring on the cap. Once the cement has cured, the o-ring won't come off unless you pry it off. The rubber cement is flexible enough it won't be bothered by the deformation of the o-ring getting crushed or by oil from inside the engine. Last of all, don't over tighten the cap when you install it. This will most likely cause the o-ring to be ripped from the cap. The idea is to just make the cap snug. This is all you need to keep the dust/debris out of the crankcase and keep the oil in.

Comment: Do garages typically have the cement u are referring to?  I think I might ask them to do it.  And by snug I take it you mean reasonably tight and not just hand tight?  Thanks

Comment: Rubber cement is a typical home product you can purchase at a craft store. As by "tight", I mean, make it snug, but don't crank it down. It just has to be tight enough to stay in place. You aren't trying to seal it for all time and eternity.

Comment: And don't re-fit the cap ***before*** the cement has cured, otherwise it will be glued on more firmly that your first broken one! Wait at least 24 hours, to be safe.

Comment: What @alephzero said ... spot on.